# Can't insert into to my Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I want to insert some info into a table but it doesn't works. This is the code.

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","Chew","*****","Birthdays");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $Name="Something";
    $Desc="Something";
    $Lang="En";
    $D="1";
    $M="1";
    echo "<br>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Birthdays` (Name, Description, Language, Day, Month) VALUES ('".$Name."', '".$Desc."', '".$Lang."', '".$D."', '".$M."' );";
    $qr= mysql_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: What data types are Day and Month columns?

Answer (score 1):

`MONTH` and `DAY` are names of [MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). If you are going to name columns with those names you *must* escape them with ticks:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Birthdays` (Name, Description, Language, `Day`, `Month`) VALUES ('".$Name."', '".$Desc."', '".$Lang."', '".$D."', '".$M."' );";
```

Answer (score 0):

read [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)

```
$qr= mysql_query($sql, $con) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

NB: mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or pdo

Answer (score 0):

If D and M are numbers, your SQL should not use quotes (') in the VALUES-part of your SQL

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Object Oriented mechanism for doing connection with MySQL with the help of MySQLi class

example

```
// The var's in complete caps means they might be defined as constant variable
// DB_HOST - database hostname
// DB_USER - database user
// DB_PASS - database password
// DB_NAME - database instance name

$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($db -> connect_error){
// in case there are errors
die("Connect Error (" . $db -> connect_errno . ") " . $db -> connect_error);
}

$Name= mysql_real_escape_string("Something"); // helps to escape special characters like quotes
$Desc= mysql_real_escape_string("Something");
$Lang="En";
$D="1";
$M="1";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `Birthdays` (Name, Description, Language, `Day`, `Month`) VALUES ('".$Name."', '".$Desc."', '".$Lang."', $D, $M );";

$db -> query($sql) or die("Error: " . $db -> error_msg);

echo "Insert id: " . $db -> insert_id;
```

EDIT: Code to fetch data from database

C_Chewbacc,

I would recommend you on reading more on PHP-MySQL connection using Object Oriented mechanism
https://www.php.net/mysqli

Try this code below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Birthdays";
$result = $db -> query($sql); // SELECT query returns result object here
// We iterate over this result object and fetch each row on every iteration
// When the resultant object has nothing to return, NULL is initialised in $row
// When $row = NULL becomes the exit point of WHILE loop
while($row = $db -> fetch_array($result)){ 
    var_dump($row); // This will display every row of data
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rsakhale, it worked. I have a question also. How do I get the selected data with SELECT * FROM 'Birthdays'?

Comment: C_Chewbacca, have added the code for fetching data, please refer my previous answer's edit :)